# Unexpected loop output

Tags: python

This code outputs 00000000 but I would think it would output 00000011, since the last 2 indexes meet the if criteria.

```
import pygame
numbers = [pygame.Color("#FFFFFF"),
            pygame.Color("#FFFFFF"),
            pygame.Color("#FFFFFF"),
            pygame.Color("#FFFFFF"),
            pygame.Color("#FFFFFF"),
            pygame.Color("#FFFFFF"),
            pygame.Color("#FF0000"),
            pygame.Color("#FF0000")]

x = 0
binary = ""
for number in numbers:
    print(number)
    if numbers[x] == pygame.Color("#FF0000"):
        binary += "1"
    elif numbers[x] == pygame.Color("#FFFFFF"):
        binary += "0"
print("after: ", binary)
```

Comment: You never change the value of x. So every time, numbers[x] is numbers[0], which is pygame.Color("#FF0000"). You are mixing two approaches to looping. Just check if number == whatever.

Comment: You are always checking the first element of the array, because you don't change _x_ value so the second condition will never be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop to this:

```
for number in numbers:
    print(number)
    if number == pygame.Color("#FF0000"):
        binary += "1"
    elif number == pygame.Color("#FFFFFF"):
        binary += "0"
```

`numbers[x]` will always point to the first element, as you aren't incrementing `x`. So, change `numbers[x]` to `number`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the index you can change the code like this:

```
binary = ""
for x, number in enumerate(numbers):
    print(number) # number = numbers[x]
    if numbers[x] == pygame.Color("#FF0000"):
        binary += "1"
    elif numbers[x] == pygame.Color("#FFFFFF"):
        binary += "0"
print("after: ", binary)
```

Comment: Just saying, if you don't need to use the index, only the value, you shouldn't use the index.

Comment: yes, of course... but sometimes it's easier to change just the line of the for loop adding the enumerate instead of changing all the variable inside the for loop. Anyway, mine was just a suggestion and an alternative to your answer (which is absolutely correct).

Comment: Yeah I realised my mistake, I am not incrementing x, but also don't actually need to iterate using x. Thanks for you help.